Crypto "chatcasts"?
So, I have an idea... this is based partly on the fact that certain things such as book lists and subjective discussion aren't great fits for the SE engine (although communities have been known to make it work. You can debate that issue here.
So my thought was - why don't we make use of the crypto chat room or perhaps a dedicated room and run organised events where we discuss, well, whatever we need to discuss. The rules of chat, aside from the usual be nice requirement, are more relaxed, so we could:

Have a session on book recommendations. We can bookmark these, kinda like this, thereby preserving them, and links to amazon onebox with pictures.
Do "introductions", such as our background, if anyone's interested in that.
Discuss site specific stuff in a slightly less ad-hoc way, like, for example tag cleanups, editing, policies etc.
???

To make this work we'd need:

Reasonable commitment to come along. 
A date and time. 
A topic.

Good idea? Bad idea? Insane idea? Suggestions? 
Update
This has received a generally positive response. I've also promoted another idea - challenges. Discussion starts here. So now, I'd like to ask when are suitable times?
I propose we run events every other week. Not so demanding as to require weekly contributions, but not as long as a month. Thoughts?

Great idea! How exactly would bookmarking work? Could we publish and organise the chats afterward as a community wiki?

@Ethan Basically, you pick a start message and an end message, give it a title and voila, the whole discussion is saved as a transcript, kinda like the example. I'm not sure what powers I do or don't have regarding moving messages around, but I can delete them and edit any chat, so we could publish a cleaned up version of the session as the bookmark. I'm going to ask on this - will get back to you.

I should also add that all chats have associated transcripts. There is only one private chat room I know of on SE, and that's for dealing with moderation issues. So basically the bookmark feature says "this bit of the chat was interesting" and gives you a direct link to it.

@EthanHeilman this is another example of a bookmarked chat. There should be a context button there which takes you to the chatroom. It also has oneboxing (nice pictures of the books) for amazon and for questions and tweets and a fair number of other things.

I like the idea. Mainly because it is something I've been doing in the Android room on [so]. Combined with the bookmark function of the chat this is also a great reference for the future. However make sure not to overdo book events. Once a month is already very frequent.

I propose the very first event have two topics:

Meet your moderators. Who are they, what do they do etc.
Ninefingers explains his crazy challenge idea.
Anything else.

In terms of time I'm best in the evenings GMT 8-11 ish, most nights of the week.
